# how to add some statistics to the plot in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

So im plotting a histogram with using `matplotlib.pyplot`

```
plt.hist(var)
```

I'm curious if I can attach some statistics to the right of the graph created by

```
var.describe()
```

for which it is a series.

the result is like this

[image: hist]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `figtext()`:

```
plt.hist(var)
plt.figtext(1.0, 0.2, var.describe())
```

[image]

Use `bbox_inches='tight'` to also save the text into a picture:

```
plt.savefig('fig1.png', bbox_inches='tight')
```

Comment: came across with earlier, didn't think of it can be used this way. thanks

Comment: The stats don't show up when I do `plt.savefig('file.png')` though. Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Added a solution to my answer.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much.

Comment: Found I needed to use str(var.describe()) to get this to work. (pandas: 1.2.4, matplotlib: 3.3.4).

Answer (score 2):

As shown in the solution above, the text formatting messes up a little bit. To fix this, I added a workaround, where we divide the description into two figures, which are then aligned.

The helper:

```py
def describe_helper(series):
    splits = str(series.describe()).split()
    keys, values = "", ""
    for i in range(0, len(splits), 2):
        keys += "{:8}\n".format(splits[i])
        values += "{:>8}\n".format(splits[i+1])
    return keys, values
```

Now plot the graph:

```
demo = np.random.uniform(0,10,100)
plt.hist(demo, bins=10)
plt.figtext(.95, .49, describe_helper(pd.Series(demo))[0], {'multialignment':'left'})
plt.figtext(1.05, .49, describe_helper(pd.Series(demo))[1], {'multialignment':'right'})
plt.show()
```

[image]

If you also want to save the figtext when saving the image refer to answer 1

Answer (score 0):

Frequently, the easiest way to do it for scatter and line plots is to stick it in the legend. This way it automatically gets positioned to the "best" place on the figure too!:

```py
plt.plot(
    df["x"].to_numpy(),
    df["y"].to_numpy(),
    'b-o', # blue line with circles
    label=f"{df['y'].describe()}"  # <==== summary stats in the legend
)
plt.legend(fontsize="x-small")  # <=== set their font size in the legend
```

[image]

Note that per [the official Pandas documentation for `.describe()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.describe.html):

> The `50` percentile is the same as the median.

So if you were wondering where the **median** was, there it is.

Other legend `fontsize` options include any integer, or these keywords: `xx-small`, `x-small`, `small`, `medium`, `large`, `x-large`, `xx-large`. See: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html.

Here is a full, runnable example:

**[`pandas_plot_scatter_add_summary_describe_statistics_to_legend.py`](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/python/pandas_plot_scatter_add_summary_describe_statistics_to_legend.py)** from my [eRCaGuy_hello_world](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world) repo, with extensive explanatory comments:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# generate sinusoidal data with some random Gaussian (normal distribution, or
# "bell curve") noise added to it

NUM_POINTS = 200
ONE_PERIOD = 2*np.pi  # 2*pi radians = 360 degrees = 1 full period
x = np.linspace(0, 2*ONE_PERIOD, NUM_POINTS)

# the standard deviation, or "width", of the noise; see:
# https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.normal.html
CENTER = 0  # mean (center) of the normal distribution
SCALE = 0.3  # standard deviation (scale) of the normal distribution
NOISE_SIZE = NUM_POINTS  # number of points in the noise
noise_array = np.random.normal(CENTER, SCALE, NUM_POINTS)

y = np.sin(x) + noise_array

# create a dataframe from the numpy arrays above
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': x, 'y': y})
print(df)

# plot the data

# fig = plt.figure(figsize=(18, 10.8))  # default is `(6.4, 4.8)` inches
fig = plt.figure()
plt.title("Sine wave with noise")
plt.plot(
    df["x"].to_numpy(),
    df["y"].to_numpy(),
    # 'bo', # blue circles, no line
    'b-o', # blue line with circles
    # add summary statistics to the legend; NB: "The 50 percentile is the same
    # as the median."; see:
    # https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.describe.html
    label=f"{df['y'].describe()}"
)
# fontsize: int or 'xx-small', 'x-small', 'small', 'medium', 'large', 'x-large',
# 'xx-large'; see:
# https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html
plt.legend(fontsize="x-small")
plt.xlabel("radians (rad)")
plt.ylabel("amplitude (-)")

plt.show()
```